# Make TableLayout Columns wrap to content

Tags: android, tablelayout

So I have the followign Layout:

```
TableLayout

    TableRow
        TextView0
        TextView1

    TableRow            
        TextView0
        TextView1
```

I"m trying to create this layout:

Course Information: Math 101
Education: Engineering

The problem is that the second column (TextView1) will be aligned to the right according to the largest text in column 1 (TextView0)
Is there any way to make the second column directly align next to the first one?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `TableLayout` - `TableRow`   and don't want to use their features... Well, then  dont use  `TableRow` . Make use of `LinearLayout` instead.

```
LinearLayout
    >TextView0
    >TextView1

LinearLayout
     >TextView0
     >TextView1
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm not disagreeing with you it's just that I have been given an application that has over 100 layout pages and all of them were made using TableLayout/Rows and asked me to change the layouts so I was hoping that there would be an easy trick to achieve that but it looks like I have to redo all of them using LinearLayout.